# Dojo 1.8 JsonRest and DataGrid

Tags: json, rest, dojo

I'm attempting to get the JsonRest functionality in Dojo 1.8. working to load a DataGrid.
I've got the Dojo client successfully talking to a REST server.  I make the call, my DataGrid headings are populated but no data is populated.  The response from the REST call is ...

{"data":{"fundId":"12345","fundDescription":"High Risk Equity Fund","bidPrice":26.8,"offerPrice":27.4,"lastUpdated":"2013-01-23T14:13:45"}}

My Dojo code is  ...

```
        require([
            "dojo/store/JsonRest",
            "dojo/store/Memory",
            "dojo/store/Cache",
            "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
            "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
            "dojo/query",
            "dojo/domReady!" 
        ], function(JsonRest, Memory, Cache, DataGrid, ObjectStore, query) {

            var restStore, memoryStore, myStore, dataStore, grid;

            restStore =  JsonRest({target:"http://localhost:8080/funds/12345"});
            memoryStore = new Memory();
            myStore = Cache(restStore, memoryStore);

            grid = new DataGrid({
                store: dataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: myStore}),

        structure: [
            {name:"Fund Id", field:"fundId", width: "200px"},
            {name:"Description", field:"fundDescription", width: "200px"},
            {name:"Bid Price", field:"bidPrice", width: "100px"},
            {name:"Offer Price", field:"offerPrice", width: "100px"},
            {name:"Last Updated", field:"lastUpdated", width: "200px"}
        ]
            }, "target-node-id"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id

            grid.startup();

            query("#save").onclick(function(){
                dataStore.save();
            });
        });
```

What am I missing to get the data successfully loaded into the grid?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be due to your `REST`-Response's `data` is not an `array` but an `object`. It should actually look like this:

```
    [{
        "fundId": "12345",
        "fundDescription": "High Risk Equity Fund",
        "bidPrice": 26.8,
        "offerPrice": 27.4,
        "lastUpdated": "2013-01-23T14:13:45"
    }]
```

The `ObjectStore` expects an `array`. As i usually don't do it the way you do, i'm not quite sure, what you have to change. But you have to make sure, that the `JSON`-Response gives you an `array`, anyway. Maybe you have to commit it to the `ObjectStore` like that later:

```
grid = new DataGrid({
    // getting data, after making sure its an array ;)
    store: dataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: myStore.get(0)}),
    ...
```

I don't know if you have to do it that way for some reasons, but for your example, the way its done in [this example](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/store_driven_grid/) should fit your need as far as i can see...

Comment: Thanks ... my response is being returned by the default implementation of Spring's MVC annotated REST support ... guess I'll need to look into that to get it to response with the proper response.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my data came from a CXF web service and looked like:
{"Customer":[{"id":1,"name":"John-1"},{"id":2,"name":"John-2"}]}

I found my answer here: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/populating_datagrid/ whereas I had to manually fetch my data from the store.

```
....
restStore.query("", {}).then(function(data){    
    dataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: new Memory({ data: data['Customer'] })}),

    grid = new DataGrid({
        store: dataStore,
        items:data.items,
        structure: [
            {name:"Customer ID", field:"id", width: "200px"},
            {name:"Customer Name", field:"name", width: "200px"}
        ]
    }, "target-node-id"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id
    grid.startup();
}
...
```

I hope this helps.
This is my first time posting so my bad if things are a bit screwy.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I've sense abandoned dojo for angular.